# Create CoApp .autopkg to copy files from redist package files to a subdirectory of the $(TargetDir)

Tags: c++, nuget, native

I am trying to package a legacy C++ project with CoApp.  The project requires the redistributable .dll's from package are copied to a subdirectory of the $(TargetDir).

I can see the following in the generated MyProj.redist.targets file:

```
<Target Name="MyProj_redist_AfterBuild" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
 <Copy SourceFiles="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)../..//build/native/bin/MyProjFoo.dll" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
 <Copy SourceFiles="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)../..//build/native/bin/MyProjBar.dll" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
</Target>
```

I need that to be:

```
<Target Name="MyProj_redist_AfterBuild" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
 <Copy SourceFiles="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)../..//build/native/bin/MyProjFoo.dll" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)\MyProj" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
 <Copy SourceFiles="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)../..//build/native/bin/MyProjBar.dll" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)\MyProj" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
</Target>
```

How do I do this in the .autopkg file?

I have tried modifying the bin rule to use :
     #add-folder : ::nuget.[redist]targets.[${condition}].CopyToOutput;

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in the CoApp issues list.  A feature to do this has been added, but the online documetation has not been updated.  See: [Issue 27 on CoApp in github](https://github.com/coapp/coapp.powershell/issues/27)